# Adding Speech to Text to .NET Core 2 bot?

Tags: bots, speech-to-text, .net-core-2.0

Are there directions available to add Speech to Text capability for a bot in .NET Core 2 framework?

I know Microsoft Cognitive Services can be used for this, but there is no sample code available in the docs for how to integrate it into the bot. Only basic 'Hi there!' bots written in Core 2 [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.NetCore-ApsNetCore2.0).

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample speech to text module in V4 framework can be found here - 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/tree/master/Samples-Http/NETCore

Resolved issue for reference - Opened this as an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4617#issuecomment-389627679) in Microsoft BotBuilder github page.